# NSTableView - I am trying to achieve data processing in background but although I use background queues, I always get a spinning ball when I scroll

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I am implementing a View Based NSTableView with a datasource and delegate.
I have a custom NSTableCellView that represents an Email object. This NSTableCellView has a 'body' TextField; filling the textfield with data is computationally expensive so I don't want to calculate all the body strings before showing the NSTableView. So I tried this:

NSTableViewDataSource:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {

    return self.myMessages.count;
}
```

NSTableViewDelegate:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row {

    EmailTableCellView *view = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"EmailTableCellView" owner:NULL];

    view.from.stringValue = [self.myMessages[row] valueForKey:@"from"];
    view.subject.stringValue = [self.myMessages[row] valueForKey:@"subject"];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY"];

    if ([self.myMessages[row] valueForKey:@"emailDate"] != NULL) {

        NSDate *date = [self.myMessages[row] valueForKey:@"emailDate"];

        view.emailDate.stringValue =  [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    }

    if ([self.myMessages[row] valueForKey:@"body"] != NULL) {
        view.body.stringValue = [self.myMessages[row] valueForKey:@"body"];

    } else {

        dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue =
        dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);


        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue,^{

            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.window.title options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:NULL];

            NSRange messageRange = NSMakeRange([[self.myMessages[row] valueForKey:@"offset"] integerValue],[[self.myMessages[row] valueForKey:@"length"] integerValue]);


            NSData *subData = [data subdataWithRange:messageRange];

            NSString *myMessageString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:subData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


            CkoEmail *myEmail = [[CkoEmail alloc] init];


            BOOL success = [myEmail SetFromMimeText:myMessageString];


            if (success) {

                if ([myEmail HasHtmlBody]) {

                    NSString *body = [myEmail GetHtmlBody];

                    body = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil] string];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

                        view.body.stringValue = body;

                    });

                } else if ([myEmail HasPlainTextBody]) {

                    NSString *body = [myEmail GetPlainTextBody];

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

                        view.body.stringValue = body;

                    });
                }



            }




        });

    }



    return view;

}
```

When I open the window containing the table I get spinning wheel for a long time, and after it stops spinning I can just scroll a few rows and it hangs again.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you ran your app on instruments using the time profiler yet? That should be the place to start, for example NSdateFormatter can be quite slow. Also, when you dispatch again to the main queue to set the body string value there’s no guarantee that the view hasn’t been reused for another row. You should validade that the view your changing is still the view for that index.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Can you point me in the right direction on how to validate the view to be certain it still is the view for that index ?

Comment: Take a look at the complex table view in the [TableViewPlayground sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html). The thumbnail image is loaded in the background.

Comment: Another useful tidbit about `NSDateFormatter`: even if you defer the date conversion to the background, and while the object itself is thread-safe, you can't preform multiple date conversions in parallel. It turns out that every date conversion obtains, and locks, some system resource (probably the timezone, user prefs, etc.) and they end up performing their conversion sequentially.

Comment: It appears that body = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil] string]; was blocking everything. Now I replaced it with a call to HTMLKit for parsing.

Comment: To Willeke: it appears that the TableViewPlayground sample code uses EmailTableCellView *updatedView = [self.myMessagesTableView viewAtColumn:0 row:row makeIfNecessary:NO]; to regather the view in the asynchronous part. Do you think that I could just regather the view in the block using that method ? I imagine I will be ok just by doing that. What do you think ? thanks

Comment: I think it's ok (on the main thread). Do you read the body every time `viewAtColumn:row:makeIfNecessary:` is called?

Comment: No, only the first time, I store it in the dictionary for each row for later times. Thanks